# How to add footer view for UITableView in IB when working with storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, autolayout

Playing around with prototype cells and I need to add footer view at the bottom of table view, so a user could see this footer view when he would scroll to the bottom of the table view. So, created demo project with one screen, table view and two prototype cells. Looking for a way how to drag and drop some view below the table using Interface Builder. The problem is it looks like view is put outside table view content, so I see the footer but I can't scroll to it (only a small part of footer view is seen at the bottom of the table view).

I know this should work because already saw a working implementation but cannot figure out what magic setting or code line I need to add.

Here are the methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section {

  return 2;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {

  CGFloat rowHeight = 10;

  switch (indexPath.row) {

    case 0: {

        rowHeight = 376;

        break;
    }
    case 1: {

        rowHeight = 105;

        break;
    }
  } 

  return rowHeight;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  switch (indexPath.row) {

    case 0: {

        Cell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell1;

        break;
    }
    case 1: {

        Cell2 *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell2;

        break;
    }
  }

  return nil;
}
```

Just making 2 row table with two different height cells. Cell1 and Cell2 classes are empty subclasses of UITableViewCell.

Here's how table view and cells look in interface builder:

[image]

Here's initial view after launch:

[image]

Here's what I see if I scroll to the bottom:

[image]

The footer is there, but outside table view (scroll content). As you can see, table view by default reserves some 44px space at the bottom for footer. But if I set footer height in tableView:heightForFooterInSection: then blank spaces appear.

Also, tried to drag and move this view up to view hierarchy in IB, so the view would become a header view. In that case, the view is shown at the top as header view, but then the second cell is shown only partially when scrolling to the bottom. It looks like table calculates how much space it needs to show prototype dynamic cells (have set "Dynamic Prototypes" for the table view). And if you add extra footer or header view to the interface builder then there's less space for the cells (if view is added as header) or the footer is not shown.

**UPDATE**. If I add this method then blank spaces appear:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  return 50;
}
```

Here's what I get in that case (blank spaces below cell2):

[image]

**UPDATE2** Footer is shown correctly if I disable autolayout.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed the following line

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return HEIGHT_OF_YOUR_FOOTER_VIEW;

}
```

**Edit**

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *footer=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320.0,50.0)];
    footer.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;


    return footer;    
}
```

**Updated**

Check this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:)

Comment: @Centurion After you added the footer height the white space suggests that the view is not added in the footer. Can you make sure, or try my edit, if it works means your view is not added in footer.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I have used frequently previously. Also was adding footer via table view property. But now I'm looking at existing code of other devs that were able to to that from IB and it's working. I have looked at the code and this method is missing. It looks like there's another way how to make this to work.

Answer (score 1):

At last found the solution. Have noticed footer is shown correctly when autolayout is disabled, so started to look at constraints. So, have added leading space to container, trailing space, bottom space and top space to container constraints to table view using Ctrl + Drag. However IB showed red warning about missing Y position constraint. So, after choosing "Add missing constraints" from IB suggestion panel, IB added another system constraint but the footer was still not show correctly. It appears IB was unable to add correct top space and bottom space to container system constraints, and even to fix that. So I'v got 5 system constraints as a result of that:

[image]

Adding system constraints using Ctrl + Drag from table view to containing view have worked in previous demos for me. However, this time IB was unable to add correct top space and bottom space to container, and so top space vertical constraint had a value of -568. Tried setting to 0 but it didn't worked. Tried ten times to delete all constraints and add them again. The same result.

So, I deleted all these vertical (bottom and space) constraints and then selected "Add missing constraints". And bingo! IB added correct vertical constraints and the footer view was shown correctly. Here's how correct constraints should look like. However, I still don't understand why IB was unable to add correct constraints when I was doing Ctrl + Drag from table view to container view.

[image]